# how to check if a variable is an Array in Javascript(noesis.Javascript) embedded in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, javascript.net

Anyone here have experience with Javascript.Net?
I'm embedding javascript in c# using [JavaScript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net).
I have simple task to check if i given variable is a valid Array or not.
I have managed to get the correct answer by attaching the variable in script.
This method works and returns `true`:

```
JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext();
public static string IsValidArray(string vari , JavascriptContext context)
        {

            object isValid = context.Run(@" 
                function check(){ var arr = " + vari + ";if(arr.constructor == Array){return true; }else {return false;}} check();");


            return (string)isValid;

        }
```

Its working fine. But when I try to pass this variable as an argument of function, it returns false.
Here's the code:

```
JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext();
string array = "['hello','hello2']";
           context.SetParameter("arr", array);
           string isValid = IsValidArray(context);

 public static string IsValidArray(JavascriptContext context)
        {        
            object isValid = context.Run("function check(vari){return (vari.constructor == Array);} check(arr);");
            return (string)isValid;          
        }
```

how to do it with arguments?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are passing a _string representation_ of an array, and not an array. You can try something like context.SetParameter("arr", new[] {"hello", "hello2"));

Comment: @A.Chiesa You are right, but I'm actually trying to parse this from a text file which contains a script. So this 'String array' comes from a text file.I wrote it like this for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate on my comment.

I think your problem is that you are passing a string representation of an array, and not an array. You can try something like context.SetParameter("arr", new[] {"hello", "hello2"));

If you have a string, and want to convert it to an object, I would suggest using Json.NET, which is simply great. Search for a tutorial on how to install it. Then you can simply do:

```
string json = "['hello','hello2']";
List<String> array = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(json);
```

The alternative, but I don't know enough of JavaScript.Net to tell you what is preferable, is to read the string as is, then pass it into JavaScript, knowing it is just a string, and then calling `JSON.parse(theString)` in JavaScript in order to interpret it as an array, or object, or whatever.